# How can I change activity without changing the state of previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I made an app to change wallpaper with 3 different activity

1. is a list of categories
2. list of wallpapers of a particular category
3. view and set the wallpaper selected

**Scenario**

When I scrolling down in 1° activity, for example, until the end and click on a category I will go to the 2° activity but when I go back, I expect to be the end of 1° activity instead I find myself at the beginning. (also 2° activity to 3° and back)

So how can I save a previous state? I used RecyclerView to make the list.
(I'm newbie on android studio, and sorry for bad english is not my first tongue)

If I had not been clear enough there is my app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yangxun.animewallpaper

These is code for wallpaper list, the 2° activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_wallpaper);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(Common.CATEGORY_SELECTED);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_wallpaper);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    loadBackgroundList();

}

private void loadBackgroundList(){ //....
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.stopListening();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home)
        finish(); //Close activity when click Back button
    return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

There is my adapter

```
public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context){
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    if(position==0)
        return CategoryFragment.getInstance();
    else
        return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return 1;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Category";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please show us the code of the list activity. It sounds like you initialise the list each time you show the activity (maybe in onResume). Or maybe you have some configuration change. Either way, we need more info to help you

Comment: Do by any chance have the kill activities option enabled in developer options? From my experience, the state and scroll position does get saved unless the activity gets recreated

Comment: hello Stein, welcome to SO! Please share a little bit of your code, especially where you configure your RecyclerView and your adapter; without it, it is just a guess game from everyone at SO trying to figure out what may be happening. We have ideas, but without concrete code and things you did/didn’t, it’s a lot harder. Thanks!

Comment: The behavior that you want to achieve is the default one. The activity takes care of saving views' states during `onSaveInstanceState` (this is only the case for views that have an id set in XML, but most likely you already have that for your RecyclerViews). So, if this is not working that means that you are doing something with your views when you get back to the first activity. E.g. if you call `setAdapter` or `notifyDataSetChanged` in activity's `onResume` or something similar, this will reset the scrolling position. So, please double check the code that executes when you restore your act 1

Comment: I added the code of list activity and the adapter, I haven't change any option since I istalled Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change

```
protected void onStop(){
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.stopListening();
    super.onStop();
}
```

to

```
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
```

And all work fine! Thanks for yours tips

Answer (score 1):

I guess you refresh the list in the Activity in `onResume` so you end up with a new list of items, which is scrolled to the top. Thats normal.

If you don't refresh the list in `onResume` you should be fine. Another approach: Save the index of the clicked item and after you get back to your list and it's refreshed call: `recyclerview.scrollToPosition(oldPosition)`